# Which fantasy novel contains the "order of the foot"?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book that I once read where wizards were divided into different factions.

One of those factions had a foot as a banner and they provide the source (e.g. the magic) that the other wizards need to do their magical works. If done properly they calculate how much a wizard needs.

Since they can only draw on magic (but not apply the energy themselves) they have to walk whereas other wizards can float/fly. Hence their order name.

**Which book am I thinking is this?**

Comment: @Jenayah - Since this question predates that one by a couple years, shouldn't that one be closed as a duplicate of this since they both have accepted "Darksword" answers?

Comment: @JohnP [related Meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4749/98028) : I voted this way because I reckon the target's answer is more detailed, and hence better, than this one's (just my opinion though :) )

Comment: @Jenayah - Thank you. I hadn't seen that clarification before. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the [*Darksword* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword) by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman.  There are 9 different categories of magic user.  The ones who supplied magic to others were known as Catalysts.  Catalysts could use very little magic but could supply it to others.

Most other magic users could fly (although those with weak magic might require the assistance of a Catalyst).  However, Catalysts typically needed to walk since they could not accept magic from another Catalyst.  Their symbol is the shoe (Thanks to [*FuzzyBoots*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23243/fuzzyboots) for pointing this out).

> Of course, our protagonist isn't. One of the cursed ones that has neither magic nor the power to fuel it. The Catalysts seem like the real victims here, by the way. Their symbol is the shoe. Because they have to WALK. Because they aren't magical like EVERYONE ELSE. But they provide juice for everyone else's magic.
>
> <sub>[Goodreads, Forging the Darksword review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/833050484?book_show_action=true)</sub>

Comment: From the review at http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/833050484?book_show_action=true:

"Of course, our protagonist isn't. One of the cursed ones that has neither magic nor the power to fuel it. The Catalysts seem like the real victims here, by the way. Their symbol is the *shoe*. Because they have to WALK. Because they aren't magical like EVERYONE ELSE. But they provide juice for everyone else's magic."

Comment: I feel uncomfortable removing your last statement to add the quote from the review, but it would be a reasonable thing for you to add. :)

Comment: thanks a lot. This certainly seems to be the one i was thinking of. been bugging me for ages